# infinite sum of analytic functions in this special case

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $\mathbf{p}=\{p_{1},p_{2},\cdots, p_{k},\cdots\}$ be a probability sequence. Let $f_{k}(t)=p_{k}^t$ for $t\geq 1$. $f_{k}(t)$ is analytic on $[1,\infty)$. But is $$f(t)=\sum_{k\geq 1}f_{k}(t)$$ analytic on $[1,\infty)$? If not (which I suspect to be the case), what kind of conditions on $\mathbf{p}$ would make $f(t)$ to be analytic?

Comment: I guess "probability sequence" means $p_k > 0$ and $\sum p_k = 1$.  If so, that implies $p_k \to 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar that's a good point; assuming the above, then $f$ is analytic on $(1, \infty)$, however a simple example like the normalization to sum $1$ of $p_k=\frac{1}{k\log^2(k+1)}$ shows that the result may not be analytic at $1$; for that a stronger condition of the type $\sum p_k^a < \infty$ for some $a<1$ is needed

Comment: @GEdgar Are you saying $f(t)$ is analytic on $(0,\infty)$ without further qualification? Why?

Comment: No, I was answering in Conrad's deleted comment saying that $p_k$ must go to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $p_k > 0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k$.  Consider the function of a complex variable
$$
F(t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k^t .
$$
Now $F(t)$ converges uniformly for $\operatorname{Re} t \le 1$ by comparison with $\sum p_k$ in the Weierstrass $M$ test.  Then note that $F$
is holomorphic in $\operatorname{Re} t > 1$ by [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).

---

What does "analytic" mean at an endpoint $1$ ?  If $\sum p_k^t$ converges for some $t_0<1$, then the same reasoning shows that $F$ is holomorphic on $\operatorname{Re} t > t_0$.